# How manually add errors in forms in play 2 framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

i'm trying addind some errors in forms but my code don't compile.
Expecially, seems that official play 2 api isn't correct.
we can see that errors() return an list of validationError
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/data/Form.Field.html#errors()

anyway if i try

```
 ValidationError e = new ValidationError("name", "user already exist",new ArrayList());
 filledForm.errors().add(e);
```

i got an error that method add don't exist.
I discovered that it is a hashmap but the follow code don't compile:

```
 filledForm.errors().put("name","s");
```

How add errors?? thanks

edit: solved thanks Julien Lafont

```
 ValidationError e = new ValidationError("name", "user already exist",new ArrayList());
 ArrayList<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
 errors.add(e);
 filledForm.errors().put("name",errors);
 return badRequest(loginForm.render(filledForm));
```

Comment: The API-doc you shared is for a Field, not a Form. You should try something like that: `myForm.field(myField).errors.put("...")`

Answer (score 12):

The short method is

> filledForm.reject("name","user already exist");
>
> return badRequest(loginForm.render(filledForm));

Comment: Just FYI, `Form.reject` works in Play java: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.8/api/java/play/data/Form.html#reject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 11):

You can use withError:

```
filledForm.withError("name", "user already exist")
```

You can add a global error too:

```
filledForm.withGlobalError("eneric error")
```

From source:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/3bebfa7c1226a438a687ec9a0a3e5c23e5aefa09/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala#L252

Comment: Just FYI, `Form.withError` works in Play Scala: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.8/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Form